# Unknown database 'database_name' in MySQL with WAMPServer

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I already have my database named als and I still got the error.

```
<?php

$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_password='';
$mysql_db='als';
$con = @mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password) or             die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($mysql_db) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: The mysql_* extension is deprecated. Better pick another API to connect to the MySQL server. See http://docs.php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing

Comment: Remove `@` and post your errors.

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\Website\connect.php on line 9 @DaveChen

Comment: @VolkerK im using this code to other pc . and it worked.

Comment: @MelvinJayBelenario Yep, you need to use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Didn't say that it switching to mysqli or PDO will fix that particular problem. Still mysql_* is deprecated - even your version of php says so. And since it looks like you don't have a ton of legacy code but are beginning your journey: now is the time to switch and use an API that is under active development and support.

Comment: oh thank you :) maybe my version of php in the other pc is outdated. I'll try mysqli. AMEN !

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to your question but too long for a comment:
After establishing the database connection you could just query the existing databases via [SHOW DATABASES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-databases.html)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    trigger_error('query failed: '.$mysqli->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$result = $mysqli->query('SHOW databases')
    or trigger_error('connect failed: '.join(',', $mysqli->error_list), E_USER_ERROR);

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo join(', ', $row), "<br />\r\n";
}
```

Does your database `als` show up?
Since you're using the default root account (with an empty password; you might want to look into that as well) there shouldn't be any permission related problems. So, if the database doesn't show up, it's just not there...

(almost) same script using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) (my weapon of choice) instead of mysqli:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'root', '', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));

foreach( $pdo->query('SHOW DATABASES', PDO::FETCH_NUM) as $row ) {
    echo $row[0], "<br />\r\n";
}
```

Comment: My database als did not appear

Comment: Then `So, if the database doesn't show up, it's just not there...` applies and that means something went wrong with `I already have my database named als` ;-)

Comment: ill try to reinstall/config mysql. Thanks by the way sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

There you go. The `mysql_` family has been deprecated for some time. Please change to the `mysqli_` library. Another machine *may* work because it's using an **older** version of PHP in which it hasn't been deprecated OR where deprecated warnings have been globally supressed.

[MySQLI Connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

**In the wild**

```
$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_password='';
$mysql_db='als';
$con= mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password, $mysql_db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
```

There's no need to arbitrarily select the database anymore. Now you can use `$con` as an argument to the `mysqli_` family of procedural functions.

Last, but not least, **never** debug with the `@` symbol. This suppresses the error warnings from the function it precedes.